# terraform convert list to string dynamically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I need to extract strings from tuple/list generated by for_each.

How to pass "account1" then "account2" in member with each role ?

```
variable "binding" {
    type = map
    default = {
        "roles/viewer" = [
            "account1",
            "account2",
        ],
        "roles/logging.viewer" = [
            "account1",
            "account2",
        ],
    }
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "test-sa-binding" {
  project = var.PROJECT_ID

  for_each = var.binding
  role    = each.key 
  member  = ???
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can do `for_each = toset(var.binding["roles/viewer"])`. I'm not really sure what is the issue? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin the issue is when trying adding other roles like "roles/viewer"

Comment: Can you provide example of such `binding` variable?

Comment: @Marcin for example, 
variable "binding" {
    type = map
    default = {
        "roles/viewer" = [
            "account1",
            "account2",
        ],
        "roles/logging.viewer" = [
            "account1",
            "account2",
        ],
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your variable first:

```
locals {
  flat_binding = merge([
      for role, accounts in var.binding:
         {
           for idx, account in accounts:
             "${role}-${idx}" => {
               account = account
               role = role
             }
         }
    ]...) # pls, do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "test-sa-binding" {
  project = var.PROJECT_ID

  for_each = local.flat_binding
  role    = each.value["role"] 
  member  = each.value["account"] 
}
```